# React Router - 500 Internal Server Error (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, create-react-app

I am tring to create separate url for my component with React Router. When I add `<Link to= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/mylink"}>mylink</Link>` and click on it - the page opens fine. But when i copy link `example.com/mysite/mylink` and open it in new window I got `500 Internal Server Error`. (This all happens on my build)

In index.js:

```
const baseUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path= {baseUrl + "/"} component={App}/>
                <Route path={baseUrl + "/mylink"} component={MyComponent}/>
           </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

.

Comment: Can you show your router file?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question

Comment: Might `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` being rendered as an empty string? That would explain why the link is working.

Comment: no, i console.log it.

Comment: Can you add a component with your `Link`? Do you use `webpack-dev-server` or your own or you dont use any?

Comment: I use create-react-app. This error happens in my build

Comment: put the screenshot of the error!

Comment: it's just regular browsers "Internal Server Error"..

Comment: @Jeremy did you manage to fix this issue? I think I've got something similar.

Comment: yes that was a server issue, you shoud setup server settings with .htaccess if Apache for example to always redirect to index.html page